# HttpServletRequest InputStream read return -1

Tags: java

I am trying to read a request `InputStream` but the end of the stream has been reached.

The only class (servlet) is:

```
    public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            InputStream clientIn = request.getInputStream();
            OutputStream clientOut = response.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int n;
            try
            {
                while ((n = clientIn.read(buffer)) != -1)    // --------->  Here, n is -1
                {
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,n));
                    clientOut.write(("Ok = " + n).getBytes());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

there is no any other classes (such as filter, listener or other servlet)

and the client code is:

```
    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {   
            String postCommand = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                    "Host: localhost\r\n" +
                    "Content-Type: binary/octet-stream\r\n" +
                    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n" +
                    "name1=value1&name2=value2";

            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
            InputStream serverIn = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream serverOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            serverOut.write(postCommand.getBytes());
            int n = 0, count = 1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            do
            {
                if (n != 0)
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, n));
                serverOut.write(("foo " + count).getBytes());
            } while ((n = serverIn.read(buffer)) != -1 && count++
```

Thank you in advance. Kind regards!

Comment: http generally has a content length header when you include data.

Comment: You can't send arbitrary data over HTTP, you have to to conform to the [HTTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). You can use raw sockets to do what you want, but then you cannot use HTTP servlets. You need to use a [`HTTPUrlConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

Comment: @bmorris591 - it is *recommended* that you use HTTPUrlConnection (or Apache HttpClient, or something), but you don't *have to* do that.

Comment: your are right, @Stephen C , i want to create a SSL Stream tunnel via servlet container, please help me around this category.

Comment: Look at below code example @ http://www.coderanch.com/t/526054/Servlets/java/Streaming-bytes-servlet

Comment: It means you reached the end of the input. That's why you wrote the loop that way. There IIs no problem here to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Your client isn't sending valid HTTP 1.1. There is no content-length header and therefore no way for the Servlet to know when to stop reading. There is no actual end of stream because an HTTP client must keep the connection open to read the response.

Use an HttpURLConnection.